# How to make synchronous $http() requests similar to $.ajax()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, request

I am making synchronous requests i.e. I always set `{async: false}`.

My problem is, while jQuery's `$.ajax()` returns whatever the response data I want it to return, AngularJs's `$http()` return a promise which is a big pain in my eyes.

Below, there's some code to demonstrate my problem.

This is jQuery:

```
// Library for sending $.ajax requests
Core.libs.prototype.send = function(...) {

    var options = {
        async: false,
        // ...
    };

    return $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {
        return data;
    });

}


// Here I make requests
let rest = Core.libs.rest(...); // Get the library
let myVar = rest.send(...); // Make the request
console.log(myVar);  // This returns an array from DB: [apple, orange] which is OK
```

And this is AngularJS:

```
// Library for sending $http requests
Core.libs.prototype.send = function(...) {

    var options = {
        async: false,
        // ...
    };

    return $http(options).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function(err) {
        return err;
    });

}


// Here I make requests
let rest = Core.libs.rest(...); // Get the library
let myVar = rest.send(...); // Make the request
console.log(myVar);  // This returns a PROMISE which is not what I want
```

Is there a way how to modify `Core.libs.prototype.send` to return actual data instead of a promise?

I would like to avoid modifying anything else than the library method.

I do not want this solution, because then I would have to replace it everywhere in my code:

```
let rest = Core.libs.rest(...); // Get the library
let myVar = rest.send(...).then(data => data);  // Make the request
console.log(myVar);  // This returns [apple, orange] but I don't want this solution
```

I also tried this, but it's not working as expected:

```
// Library for sending $http requests
Core.libs.prototype.send = async function(...) {

    var options = {
        // ...
    };

    let res = await $http(options).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function(err) {
        return err;
    });

    return res; 

}


// Here I make requests
let rest = Core.libs.rest(...); // Get the library
let myVar = rest.send(...); // Make the request
console.log(myVar);  // This still returns a PROMISE. Why?
```

Comment: "I am making synchronous requests i.e. I always set {async: false}." — Well stop. That functionality is deprecated for good reason.

Comment: You need to face the pain. You can use `async`/`await` instead of `.then()` callbacks, that way you can basically write "synchronous" code.

Comment: @Quentin I am using jQuery 1.5

Comment: I think Quentin's remark was not regarding any specific jQuery version. _Browsers_ will start blocking synchronous background requests in the not-too-far future, you should already see warnings about this in the browser console.

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery 1.5 **either** because it is unsupported and doesn't get security patches, but as CBroe said, that wasn't my point.

Comment: @ChrisG @Quentin @CBroe I have updated the question (at the end of the question) with my bad attempt with async/await. Why is it not working? Do I really have to put `await` before every `rest.send(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should embrace promise/async await but that is not the point of your question. To achieve what you want, you either call using the `async/await` notation or `then()` clause, but not together:

```
// Library for sending $http requests
Core.libs.prototype.send = async function(...) {

    var options = {
        // ...
    };

    try {
      const response = await $http(options);
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
}
```